# NoSQL Structure for handling labeled tags

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, cloudant, nosql

Currently I have a hundreds of thousands of files like so:

```
{
    "_id": "1234567890",
    "type": "file",
    "name": "Demo File",
    "file_type": "application/pdf",
    "size": "1400",
    "timestamp": "1491421149",
    "folder_id": "root"
}
```

Currently, I index all the names, and a client can search for files based on the name of the file. These files also have `tags` that need to be associated with the file but they also have specific labels.

An example would be:

```
{
    "tags": [
        { "client": "john doe" },
        { "office": "virginia" },
        { "ssn": "1234" }

    ]
}
```

Is adding the `tags` array to my above file object the ideal solution if I want to be able to search thousands of files with a client of **John Doe**?

The only other solution I can think of is having something an object per tag and having an array of file ID's associated with each tag like so:

```
{
    "_id": "11111111",
    "type": "tag",
    "label": "client",
    "items": [
        "1234567890",
        "1222222222",
        "1333333333"
    ]
}
```

With this being a LOT of objects I need to add tags to, I'd rather do it the most efficient way possible FIRST so I don't have to backtrack in the near future when I start running into issues.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original design, with a tags array, works well with Cloudant Search: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/search.html#search.

With this approach you would define a single design document that will index any tag in the tags array. You do not have to create different views for different tags and you can use the Lucene syntax for queries: http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Overview.

So, using your example, if you have a document that looks like this with tags:

```
{
  "_id": "1234567890",
  "type": "file",
  "name": "Demo File",
  "file_type": "application/pdf",
  "size": "1400",
  "timestamp": "1491421149",
  "folder_id": "root",
  "tags": [
    { "client": "john doe" },
    { "office": "virginia" },
    { "ssn": "1234" }
  ]
}
```

You can create a design document that indexes each tag like so:

```
{
  "_id": "_design/searchFiles",
  "views": {},
  "language": "javascript",
  "indexes": {
    "byTag": {
      "analyzer": "standard",
      "index": "function (doc) {\n  if (doc.type === \"file\" && doc.tags) {\n    for (var i=0; i<doc.tags.length; i++) {\n      for (var name in doc.tags[i]) {\n        index(name, doc.tags[i][name]);\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}"
    }
  }
}
```

The function looks like this:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.type === "file" && doc.tags) {
    for (var i=0; i<doc.tags.length; i++) {
      for (var name in doc.tags[i]) {
        index(name, doc.tags[i][name]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you would search like this:

```
https://your_cloudant_account.cloudant.com/your_db/_design/searchFiles/_search/byTag
?q=client:jack+OR+office:virginia
&include_docs=true
```

Comment: Thank you Mark for the in depth answer, I really appreciate it.

Comment: If I also want to make name searchable, would it be worth it to just add `index("name", doc.name);` on line to above the if statement? Or should I create an entirely new index?

Comment: I think it would make sense to add it to the same index. The only issue would be if you have a tag called "name" then you would have a conflict. Not exactly sure what would happen there...

Comment: You're the man Mark. I've been using standard map functions with views and this completely blew my mind. I don't know much have how the indexing works, but would be super interested in learning the difference in doing the above for lets say searching the name of a document vs doing something like `function (doc) { emit([doc.timestamp], [doc._id, doc.type]);}'`

Answer (score 0):

The solution, that comes into my mind would be using map reduce functions.

To do that, you would add the tags to your original document:

```
{
    "_id": "1234567890",
    "type": "file",
    "name": "Demo File",
    "file_type": "application/pdf",
    "size": "1400",
    "timestamp": "1491421149",
    "folder_id": "root",
    "client": "john",
    ...
}
```

Afterwards, you can create a design document, that looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": "_design/query",
    "views": {
        "byClient": {
            "map": "function(doc) { if(doc.client) { emit(doc.client, doc._id) }}"
        }
    }
}
```

After the view is processed, you can open it with

`GET /YOURDB/_design/query/_view/byClient?key="john"`

By adding the query parameter `include_docs=true`, the whole document will be returned, instead of the id.

You can also write your tags into an tags attribute, but you have to update the map function to match the new design.

More information about views can be found here:
http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/ddoc/views.html

Comment: Thanks but I wasn't asking how to perform a search I was asking what the most appropriate way to structure my data would be